# Button on uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm having a problem with button on uitableview. As in the code, when i click on the button  of each cell the image Checked.png should be shown on the button. THis is working fine. However, when i scroll the tableview, the checked image on top of the table disappear.How do i solve this. Can any kind person please help me on this?

```
//table.m//

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
//- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell" owner:self options:NULL];
    cell = nibLoadedCell;

    button *toggleControl = [[CheckBox alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(270.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0)];
    toggleControl.tag = toggleControlTag;
    [cell.contentView addSubview: toggleControl];
    [toggleControl addTarget:self action:@selector(Selected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    }       

//button.m//

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

  if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        // Initialization code
        self.contentHorizontalAlignment  = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;

        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

      }
       return self;

 }

-(IBAction) checkBoxClicked{
    if(self.isChecked ==NO){
        self.isChecked =YES;
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }else{
        self.isChecked =NO;
        [self setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }

}
```

Comment: Please mark all the code as code (highlight and click the 101010 button). It is impossible to read this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the state for the button in the button. That is the wrong approach. The button is only the view for the state. You need to store your data elsewhere, e.g. in an array, and pull the relevant data for a table cell from the array depending on the indexPath for that cell.

When someone presses your button, you can, e.g., set a BOOL in your data model to indicate that this particular option was selected by the user.

Your cells will always scroll off the view, which will lead to the cells being reused, and your button will no longer be "valid". So you need to check, for every cell that you create, what data you have in your model for this particular part of your data, and fill in the view (= the cell) accordingly.

It wouldn't harm to [read up on design patterns.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/01_Overview.html)